possible to set containerlab with external ip?
I am planning on using kubernetes in wsl to create a pod. within the pod, I create containers using containerlab. Followed by giving the containers external ip addresses that can be accessed from wsl.
Internal IP of containerlab: 172.20.20.0/24
External IP of node1 in containerlab: 10.151.232.12 #for example.

I have read multiple documents but still they do not say much about this. So I am asking if it is possible?

Follow the below steps to create a Kubernetes pod in WSL, run containers using Containerlab, and assign external IPs (e.g., 10.151.232.12) to the containers that are available from WSL by configuring networking.
Set up Kubernetes (using k3s or minikube) in WSL.
Install Containerlab and define your network topology, assign IPs (e.g., 10.151.232.12) to the containers.
Configure networking:
Enable IP forwarding in WSL using sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip\_forward=1.
Use iptables or NAT rules to route traffic between the WSL environment and external IPs in the Containerlab network.
Verify connectivity from both Kubernetes pods and WSL to the external IPs of the containers.With correct networking configuration (e.g., NAT or bridging), the external IPs should be reachable from both Kubernetes and WSL.
